# Can't stop the program - Python

Tags: python

```
import time

number = int(input("Enter a number : "))

def printer(number):
    a = 0
    while a <= number:
        print("This works!!! \n Great!!!")
        a += 1
        if a == number/2:
            check = int(input("Enter a prime number to stop this printing : "))
            count = 2
            x = 0
            while count < check:
                    if check % count == 0:
                        x += 1 
                        count += 1
            if x == 0:
                break

        time.sleep(0.5)

printer(number)
```

This program doesn't end after line 11. I have to stop it manually by pressing `Ctrl + C`. I'm new to Python , please help me.

Comment: If `check % count` is not `0`, then `count` or `check` are not updated, so you keep looping in the inner `while` loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot , brother. Now , should I delete my question as my problem is done? I'm new to this site.

Comment: It works now. @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: When you press `Ctrl+C`, you should be able to identify where it's stuck.

Comment: This question is so specific to this programming task, that I don't believe it would bring much to SO to leave it here. The general turn of events is submitting the solution as an answer, and then you can mark it as such, but the reuse value of this question is quite limited. You can delete it if you want,  @NewbieCoder